Generate inetersection type from an array of class constructors
Say that I have an array with class constructors such as
const arr = [A, B, C, D]

How can I map this type into an intersection of these items? Like
type IntersectedTypes = A & B & C & D

But in a way that will work for different arrays.
I tried doing type IntersectedTypes = (typeof arr)[number] but that just gives me the union type typeof A | typeof B | typeof C | typeof D

Seems like a very slight variation on UnionToIntersection. Have you looked that up and tried it? If nobody else gets here and explains I’ll do so when I get off mobile.

The real magic here is that you need a "union to intersection" type. The member type of an array is a union, but you need to get the intersection of that union.
See this fantastic answer for that: Transform union type to intersection type

But the next problem is that you will have:
typeof A & typeof B & ...

Which isn't what you want. That is the type of the class constructors, not the types of the instances of those constructors.  So you just need to use InstanceType to get the instance type from those constructors.
Full example:
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (x: U)=>void : never) extends ((x: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

class A { a = true }
class B { b = 'b' }
class C { c = 123 }
class D { d = { value: 'd' } }

const arr = [A, B, C, D]

type IntersectedTypes = UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<typeof arr[number]>>

const test: IntersectedTypes = { // fine
    a: false,
    b: 'a string',
    c: 456,
    d: { value: 'another string' }
}

See playground
